# How to analytically continue this function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, analytic-continuation

I was wondering if it would be possible to get an analytically continuation of the following function:

$$ J(x) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \ln(r)x^r $$

### My attempt

Consider the following:

**(1)**
$$ J'(x) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty r \ln(r) x^{r-1}$$

We also know:

**(2)**
$$ \frac{J}{1-x} = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \ln(r!) x^r$$

Elaborating on **(2)**

$$ J = \ln(2) x^2 + \ln(3) x^3 + \dots $$

Dividing by $1-x$ and expanding on the R.H.S:

$$ \implies \frac{J}{(1-x)} = \ln(2)(x^2 + x^3 + \dots) + \ln(3)(x^3 + x^4 + \dots) + \dots$$

Combining all the powers of $x$

$$ \frac{J}{1-x} = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \ln(r!) x^r$$

Adding **(1)** and **(2)** and multiplying by $x$

$$  x J'(x) + \frac{x J(x)}{1-x} = \sum_{r=1}^\infty (r \ln (r) + \ln(r-1)!) x^r$$

Using the identity: $ \sum_{r=1}^n (r \ln (r) + \ln(r-1)!) = n \ln n!$

$$ \implies \frac{x J'(x)}{(1-x_)} + \frac{x J(x)}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{r=1}^\infty r \ln(r!) x^r$$

Differentiating **(2)** and multiplying $x$ and comparing:

$$ \implies \frac{x J'(x)}{(1-x_)} + \frac{x J(x)}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{J'(x)}{1-x} - \frac{J(x)}{(1-x)^2} $$

Solving:

$$ J(x) = c \exp(\frac{-2}{x-1})(x-1) $$

But this can't be correct! Can someone point out where I went wrong?

Comment: If we define $\text{Li}_s(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^s}$ then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log(k)\frac{z^k}{k^s} = -\frac{d}{ds}\text{Li}_s(z)$ so your sum is $J(z) = \left[-\frac{d}{ds}\text{Li}_s(z)\right]_{s=0}$. The function $\text{Li}_s$ is known as the [polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) and you can find info about how to analytically continue it for example [here](http://www.ramapodesign.com/bruce/math/math.php?f=polylog.html).

Comment: @Winther Thank you .... any idea where my attempt went wrong? I think I solved the differential equation wrong but even the correction  (I'm thinking ) of it doesn't seem to do the trick ...

Comment: I now have checked your derivation in detail (my last observations was wrong, sorry about that). Everything seems fine until "Differentiating (2) and multiplying $x$ and comparing". You forgot to multiply the RHS by $x$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{J(x)}{1-x} = \frac{J'(x)}{1-x} \color{red}{+} \frac{J(x)}{(1-x)^2}$. We now get that the LHS is identical to the RHS so we get no ODE out of this just the identity $0=0$.